# How do I connect ember app to API running on localhost:4000 virtual machine?

Tags: api, ember.js, ember-data, virtual-machine

I tried changing the adapter host to localhost:4000, but all I see is "network error occurred" in the console.

Comment: Instead of localhost, you might need to mention machine name

Comment: what did you try exactly?

Comment: use the exact ip of that machine. (use `ipconfig /all` or `ifconfig -a` in virtual machine to get the exact ip)